# When does refraction begin?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, refraction, quantum-optics

As a wave function (a single quantum of field excitation) enters a refractory medium, does it begin to refract only after the entire wavelength has entered or does the leading edge of the wavelength exhibit refraction before the entire wave function has entered?  I realize this is all happening in a Planck time but has any experiment been devised to show exactly when refraction begins?

Comment: I suppose I could ask, is it required that any single quantum of field excitation in one medium fully decohere before its state is translated to another medium? Or are there intermediary stages that "build" toward full translation?

Comment: If you were talking a single photon there is no wave. Also there's no guarantee the photon will continue through the medium. It may be absorbed on the first surface and then re-emitted in the opposite direction.

Comment: Assuming it IS absorbed does the "absorption" occur as a discrete instantaneous event or is it absorbed as a gradient??

Comment: An electron would be instantly raised to a higher energy level followed by a new photon being instantly emitted in a random direction. It would take millions or billions of coherent photons to resemble a wave.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying photon vs wave.  That's not really what I was concerned with.  So you're saying that the quantum state of the photon as it exists in the plancktime before it strikes the medium is retranslated in the energy state of an emmitance in a discrete manner.  I would assume that prior to being emitted, an excitation has instantly occurred upon an electron on the surface of the medium and it is THAT new quantum state of the electron which is emitted as a field excitation.  Is there any time intervening between that last plancktime BEFORE striking the surface and the emittance?

Comment: Yes but not certain frequencies are absorbed and re-emitted.

Comment: Or...is there a plancktime accounting for the state of the excited surface electron and another plancktime accounting for the emittance.

Comment: Could you rephrase that?

Comment: Ok...there is a plancktime in which is described a quantum state PRIOR to striking the surface.  A 2nd plancktime in which is described the quantum state of surface excitation.  A 3rd plancktime in which is described the next behavior of that field excitation...be it reflection, refraction, difraction...etc  And these changes are each discrete and instantaneous keeping in mind that 3 plancktimes elapse (with instantaneous change for each plancktime)?

Comment: They are definitely changes or transfers of energy. Each with an associated amount of time. I wouldn't say instant as in no time considering light does have a finite speed.

Comment: I'm asking if the change is instant while the condition of being in that state is encompassed by a timeframe.  For a photon that timeframe would be 1 plancktime.

Comment: I guess I can't answer that exactly. Or I'm still not sure what you're asking

Comment: I'm pretty sure you understand the question.  I can't answer it exactly yet either...which is why I asked here.  But thanks.  Maybe an answer is out there somewhere. :-)

Comment: I was asking because I thought it might help me with:    https://www.facebook.com/approaching42/   Just a bit of conjectural exercise.